# Is it safe to expose signalR connectionId of one client to another client?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr

The scenario I'm working in is

`Client X` connects to `Hub A`.

`Client X` does some actions that cause it to push information to `Hub A`

`Hub A` dissects that information and broadcasts it to everyone else in `Hub A`

**Then**

`Client Y` connects to `Hub A`

At this point, I'm alerting the current clients in `Hub A` (`Client X`) that a new client has joined the hub. In that broadcast, I'm including Client Y's `connectionId`

`broadcastToExistingClientsOfNewUser(client_y_connectionId);`

Then each client that already exists in `Hub A` can choose to react to that information if they need to.

My concern is that I'm not sure of the implications of exposing the connectionId of `Client Y` to `Client X`. Other then being able to spam `Client Y`, is there any concern when sharing a connectionId ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find an exact answer to my question, but I found a supported solution. [Single-user groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#single-user-groups)

Essentially, I can encapsulate the one-to-one nature and uniqueness of trying to communicate to a single connectionId by using a group with a key value that is safe for me to expose to other connections. This allowed me to not have to manually track connectionIds myself, and just let SignalR handle the management of connections.